# Can Hazard Ratio be translated into ratio of medians of survival time?

Tags: survival, hazard

In one paper describing results of survival analysis I have read a statement that implies that one can translate Hazard ratio (HR) into ratio of median survival times ($M_1$ and $M_2$) using the formula:

$HR = \frac{M_1}{M_2}$

I'm sure it doesn't hold when one cannot assume proportional hazard model (as nothing works if HR is not well-defined). But I suspect, that even then it wouldn't work for any survival distribution except exponential. Is my intuition right?

Comment: Like the first person I am interested in calculating a hazard ratio (HR) from a ratio of survival times (assuming the distributional assumptions hold). I just wanted to add a point of clarification Suppose I want to calculate the HR for treatment 1 versus 2 Median survival on treatment 1 is 1 years (M1=1)
Median survival on treatment 2 is 2 year (M2=2) then surely my HR for treatment 1 versus 2 is M2/M1 = 2 and not
M1/M2 = 1/2 so we have to reverse the signs, am I right? Jack

Comment: For anyone interested in the topic, I found today this relevant work by Cortés et al: 
https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/338196/Brief_Report.pdf

Comment: Very interesting and useful. I just want to note that the [mentioned paper by Cortes et al.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56837/can-hazard-ratio-be-translated-into-ratio-of-medians-of-survival-time/603744#comment1114916_56837) was a draft manuscript, and the final formal paper was published in Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, with a different title and probably improvements [http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2014.05.017](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2014.05.017)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The following relationship between survival functions holds:
$$
S_1(t)=S_0(t)^r
$$
where $r$ is the hazard ratio (see, e.g. the Wikipedia article [Hazard ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_ratio)). From this we may show that your statement implies an exponential survival function.

Let us denote the medians by $M_r$, $M_1$ for two variables with hazard ratio $r$. Your statement implies 
$$
M_r = M_0/r
$$
From the definition of the median, we get
$$
S_r(M_0/r)=0.5
$$ 
Then, we substitute the relationship between survival functions
$$
S_0(M_0/r)^r=0.5 \Rightarrow S_0(M_0/r) = 0.5^{1/r}
$$
This holds for any $r$, hence
$$
S_0(t) = 0.5^{t/M_0} = e^{t\frac{\log 0.5}{M_0}}
$$
Hence, if the statement in your question holds for arbitrary HR, the survival distribution must be exponential.

Comment: (+1) concise, yet very clear explanation.